# Why are my custom gutenberg attributes not saved after safing the post?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I' trying to create a custom gutenberg block, that allows to add one or more images and videos in the editor and save it to the frontend.

So i added an array that receives 4 entries per media:

1. ID of the selected media item
2. the media type (either "image" oder "video")
3. the url
4. the alt-text

```
"attributes": {
        "mediaItems": {
            "type": "array",
            "source": "query",
            "selector": ".instagram-media",
            "default": [],
            "query": {
                "mediaID": {
                    "type": "number",
                    "source": "attribute",
                    "attribute": "data-id"
                },
                "mediaType": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "source": "attribute",
                    "attribute": "data-type",
                    "selector": ".instagram-media"
                },
                "mediaURL": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "source": "attribute",
                    "attribute": "src"
                },
                "mediaAlt": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "source": "attribute",
                    "attribute": "alt"
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

In the edit.js I try to receive the selected media and store the url, alt, id and type in the attributes via the getMedia function. I need the type to provide a different markup based on the mediatyp (image or video).

```
import { __ } from '@wordpress/i18n';
import { useBlockProps, RichText, InspectorControls, InnerBlocks, MediaUploadCheck, MediaUpload } from '@wordpress/block-editor';
import { PanelBody, Button, ResponsiveWrapper, Spinner } from '@wordpress/components';
import { Component, Fragment } from '@wordpress/element';
import { compose } from '@wordpress/compose';
import { withSelect } from '@wordpress/data';
import './editor.scss';

const ALLOWED_MEDIA_TYPES = [ 'image', 'video' ];

 class mediaSelectorEdit extends Component {
    render() {
        const { attributes, setAttributes, media} = this.props;
        const { mediaID } = attributes;
        const instructions = <p>{ __( 'To edit the Post Mediadaten, you need permission to upload media.', 'post-media-selector' ) }</p>;
        const className = "wp-block-" + this.props.name.replace("/", "-")

        const onUpdatemedia = ( mediaItems ) => {
            setAttributes( {
                mediaItems: mediaItems.map( item => {
                    return {
                        mediaID: parseInt( item.id, 10 ),
                        mediaType: item.type,
                        mediaURL: item.url,
                        mediaAlt: item.alt
                    };
                } ),
            } );
        };

        const onRemovemedia = () => {
            setAttributes( {
                mediaID: undefined,
            } );
        };

        return (
            <Fragment>
                <InspectorControls>
                    <PanelBody
                        title={ __( 'Post Mediadaten Einstellung', 'post-media-selector' ) }
                        initialOpen={ true }
                    >
                        <div className="wp-block-post-media-selector-media">
                            <MediaUploadCheck fallback={ instructions }>
                                <MediaUpload
                                    title={ __( 'Post Mediadaten', 'post-media-selector' ) }
                                    onSelect={ onUpdatemedia }
                                    allowedTypes={ ALLOWED_MEDIA_TYPES }
                                    value={ mediaID }
                                    multiple={ true }
                                    render={ ( { open } ) => (
                                        <Button
                                            className={ ! mediaID ? 'editor-post-featured-media__toggle' : 'editor-post-featured-media__preview' }
                                            onClick={ open }>
                                            { ! mediaID && ( __( 'Post Mediadaten hochladen', 'post-media-selector' ) ) }
                                            { !! mediaID && ! media && <Spinner /> }
                                            { !! mediaID && media &&
                                                <ResponsiveWrapper
                                                    naturalWidth={ media.media_details.width }
                                                    naturalHeight={ media.media_details.height }
                                                >
                                                    <img src={ media.source_url } alt={ __( 'Post Mediadaten', 'post-media-selector' ) } />
                                                </ResponsiveWrapper>
                                            }
                                        </Button>
                                    ) }
                                />
                            </MediaUploadCheck>
                            { !! mediaID && media &&
                                <MediaUploadCheck>
                                    <MediaUpload
                                        title={ __( 'Post Mediadaten', 'post-media-selector' ) }
                                        onSelect={ onUpdatemedia }
                                        allowedTypes={ ALLOWED_MEDIA_TYPES }
                                        value={ mediaID }
                                        render={ ( { open } ) => (
                                            <Button onClick={ open } isDefault isLarge>
                                                { __( 'Ersetze Post Mediadaten', 'post-media-selector' ) }
                                            </Button>
                                        ) }
                                    />
                                </MediaUploadCheck>
                            }
                            { !! mediaID &&
                                <MediaUploadCheck>
                                    <Button onClick={ onRemovemedia } isLink isDestructive>
                                        { __( 'Entferne Post Mediadaten', 'post-media-selector' ) }
                                    </Button>
                                </MediaUploadCheck>
                            }
                        </div>
                    </PanelBody>
                </InspectorControls>

                <div className={ className }>
                    <div className="instagram-post__media-container">
                        {attributes.mediaItems[0] !== undefined &&
                            attributes.mediaItems.map(media => {
                                if(media.mediaType === "video") {
                                    return (
                                        <div className={"instagram-post__media-container__media " + media.mediaType}>
                                            <picture className="startframe"></picture>
                                            <picture className="endframe"></picture>
                                            <video src={ media.mediaURL } className="instagram-media"></video>
                                        </div>
                                    )
                                } else if(media.mediaType === "image") {
                                    return (
                                        <picture className={"instagram-post__media-container__media " + media.mediaType}>
                                            <source srcset={media.mediaURL} />
                                            {media2XURLGenerator(media.mediaURL) !== undefined &&
                                                <source srcset={media2XURLGenerator(media.mediaURL) + " 2x"} />
                                            }
                                            <img src={media.mediaURL} alt={media.mediaAlt} className="instagram-media" />
                                        </picture>
                                    )
                                }
                            })
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
            </Fragment>
        )
    }
}

export function media2XURLGenerator(mediaURL) {
    const mediaLast = mediaURL.split(".").pop()
    const urlFirst = mediaURL.replace(`.${mediaLast}`, "")

    return `${urlFirst}_2x.${mediaLast}`
}

export default compose(
    withSelect( ( select, props ) => {
        const { getMedia } = select( 'core' );
        const { mediaID } = props.attributes;

        return {
            media: mediaID ? getMedia( mediaID ) : null,
        };
    } ),
)( mediaSelectorEdit );
```

And last but not least that is my save.js

```
 import { __ } from '@wordpress/i18n';
 import { useBlockProps } from '@wordpress/block-editor';
 import { media2XURLGenerator } from './edit'

 export default function save( { attributes } ) {
    const blockProps = useBlockProps.save();
    const { mediaItems } = attributes;

    console.log(attributes.mediaItems[0])
     return (
        <div
            { ...blockProps }
        >
            <div className="instagram-post__media-container">
                {attributes.mediaItems.map(media => {

                    const { mediaURL, mediaAlt, mediaType } = media
                    if(media.mediaType === "video") {
                            return (
                                <div className={"instagram-post__media-container__media " + "video"}>
                                    <picture className="startframe"></picture>
                                    <picture className="endframe"></picture>
                                    <video src={ media.mediaURL } data-type="video" className="instagram-media"></video>
                                </div>
                            )
                    } else if(media.mediaType === "image") {
                        return (
                            <picture className={"instagram-post__media-container__media " + "image"}>
                                <source srcset={media.mediaURL} />
                                {media2XURLGenerator(media.mediaURL) !== undefined &&
                                    <source srcset={media2XURLGenerator(media.mediaURL) + " 2x"} />
                                }
                                <img src={media.mediaURL} alt={media.mediaAlt} data-type="image" className="instagram-media" />
                            </picture>
                        )
                    }
                })}
            </div>
        </div>
     );
 }
```

So, what is my problem?

I always get an error in the console (after saving the block). The error says that my post-body and save.js code not similar is. That causes from the if-statement in the save.js. The mediaType attribute always returns undefined - but only after the post is saved. While editing the logs show exactly what I'm expecting (either image or video).

I think there is a problem with saving my attributes. After post reload in the editor they're always gone.

Hope somebody can help me.

Answer (score 2):

In your `save()` function, the [query for attributes](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-attributes/#query-source) defined in your `block.json` looks for elements with the class selector `.instagram-media`, but it doesn't exist so unfortunately no attributes are saved.

Below is a simplified version of what your `save()` would need to contain for your attributes query in `block.json` to save the expected attributes array:

**Eg.**

```js
export default function save() {
    return (
        <div {...useBlockProps.save()}>
            <img
                className="instagram-media"
                data-id="1" 
                data-type="image"
                src="image1.jpg"
                alt="first"
            />
            <img
                className="instagram-media"
                data-id="2"
                data-type="image"
                src="image2.jpg"
                alt="second"
            />
            <img
                className="instagram-media"
                data-id="3" 
                data-type="image"
                src="image3.jpg"
                alt="third"
            />
            <img
                className="instagram-media"
                data-id="4"
                data-type="image"
                src="image4.jpg"
                alt="fourth"
            />
        </div>
    );
}
```

**NB.** Remove `"selector": ".instagram-media"` from `"mediaType": {...}`in your block.json - it is *only* needed in `"mediaItems":{...}` where the `query` is defined.

Your actual code is more complex, but I hope the simplified example helps you see how to alter your `.map()`  iteration to get the desired result.

Another approach for this kind of block would be to use [InnerBlocks](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/block-tutorial/nested-blocks-inner-blocks/) to create a custom Parent block that can only contain either your custom ImageBlock or VideoBlock. It does requires creating 3 blocks; but would be easier to maintain and update with simple attributes and removes the need for  the `if` statement in `save()`.